# Subversion control using tortoisesvn

Tags: php, svn, version-control, tortoisesvn

I'm new to subversion control. I'm working on a PHP project in my localhost and I want to share my work with another person from another system so that he can also make changes to the same project. I wanted to use TortoiseSVN for this. Do I need a server for storing my repository? How can I do this? Can anybody suggest me a good tutorial (video may be) so that I can do it myself. I'm sorry if this is an off topic. But I searched a lot for this but couldn't come up with something that fits me.

Comment: Do you mind the code to be public? It might easier to use Google Code to host then to setup your own server. Also if you aren't dead set on SVN, there is GitHub or BitBucket that use Git. Git is very similar to SVN.

Comment: @JoshuaBixler Git follows different version-control paradigm than Subversion. While workflow with both of them may look "similar" (whatever you mean by this statement), Subversion is much easier to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. TortoiseSVN is **client**, in order to share repository in Net, you must to use **server** (own or 3-rd party)
2. There are a lot of (free and not-free) SCM-hostings in the world
3. Easiest and fastest and easily understood way to have http-based repository on Windows host is [VisualSVN Server](http://www.visualsvn.com/server/)
4. In terms of manageability, accessibility and added (on top of pure repository) functionality SVN-hosting is better way (checked and confirmed by my own experience)